# Crop image file with quality lost

Tags: android, crop

I use the following code to let the user pick a picture from the gallery. Then the user can crop it. The result is written in an output file. The problem is that the output file has much less quality than the original. Is there a way to have it without quality loose.
Thanks.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");

        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        File fileOut = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Outputfile.png");
        intent.putExtra("output", Uri.fromFile(fileOut));
        intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG); 
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.loEditarPerfiles_SeleccioneImagen)), 1234567);
```

Comment: is there any change when you put this: `int x = 200; int y = 200; intent.putExtra("outputX", x);    
   intent.putExtra("outputY", x);`?

Comment: solved? can u post solution?